# mount: / not mounted already, or bad option

Tags: centos, mount, fstab

Can't mount the system with data=writeback
I've added ,data=writeback to fstab than
fstab:

```
/dev/mapper/vg-lv_root                  /               ext4    defaults,noatime,discard,data=writeback     1 1
```

mount:

```
mount -o remount /
mount: / not mounted already, or bad option
```

i'm using:

```
Centos 6.2 64bit
Linux 3.0.0+ #1 SMP Fri Oct 26 07:55:47 EEST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```